# Updating PeerJS Data Handler Callback Function at Runtime

Tags: javascript, callback, peerjs

I am using PeerJS in my project.

I have successfully implemented and documented a data handler for the peer connection, as described in the PeerJS documentation: ([docs](https://peerjs.com/docs/#dataconnection-on))

```
connection.on('data', data => peerOnDataHandler(data, connection));
```

However, I now need to update the callback function at runtime. The reason for this is that there is a state within my function `peerOnDataHandler()` that requires updating.

I attempted to update the callback function using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work as expected, or perhaps I am not using it correctly:

```
connection.off('data', data => peerOnDataHandler(data, connection));
connection.on('data', data => peerOnDataHandler(data, connection));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing a new function as callback to `.off()` and `.on()`. You need to have a reference to original function:

```
const ref = data => peerOnDataHandler(data, connection);
connection.off('data', ref);
//you can update the state inside "peerOnDataHandler"
connection.on('data', ref);
```